# Error on jest when I try to run the test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native

This is the error in the console: `Cannot find module 'expo' from 'setup.js'`.

Below is my code:

**component.test.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from '../components/Component';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('create component correctly', () =>{
   const tree = renderer.create(
       <MyComponent/>
   ).toJSON();
   expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

**Component.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
   render(){
       return(
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
              <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
                  <Text> Test Component </Text>
              </View>
          </View>
      );
   }
}
```

When I try to use npm test the error that I mentioned before appears and I already try to uninstall and re-install jest and the error keeps showing.

Comment: I'm getting the same error after ejecting. Not using any expo APIs in my code. Did you eject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `create-react-native-app`, looks like this is coming from the "jest-expo" preset in the jest configuration.

Replace it with the `react-native` Jest preset, which is now built in to Jest:

**jest.config.js:**

`module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native'
};`

Or in **package.json**:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Comment: I did this and also I used `npm prune` to clear the dependencies and after that I install the dependencies again with the missing dependencies and it's working fine. Thanks this help me!